# PHP : What does this statement mean? if ($isCopy = null !== $id) { // do something }

Tags: php, symfony

I have this following legacy piece of code in my php file:

```
$id = $request->getParameter('id', null);
if ($isCopy = null !== $id) {
     // Do domething
}
```

What I undertand is, it is fetching parameter 'id' from URL and checking if it is NULL.
I want to understand how this logic works? `if ($isCopy = null !== $id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interpreted as follows:

```
$id = $request->getParameter('id', null);
if ($isCopy = (null !== $id)) {
     // Do domething
}
```

$isCopy receives the boolean result from the null !== $id comparison, then it's value is used by the if statement.

This kind of construct should be avoided, though.
Use this instead:

```
$id = $request->getParameter('id', null);
if ($id !== null) {
     // Do domething
}
```

Or, if you are carrying the evaluation down to another block of code, and want to highlight the meaning of the null id:

```
$id = $request->getParameter('id', null);
$isCopy = $id !== null;
if ($isCopy) {
     // Do domething
}
```

Comment: i see, so `null` in `$request->getParameter('id', null);` is of any use?

Comment: Usually it defines the default value to be returned if the id parameter is not present in the request. This depends on the signature and implementation of your Request class.

Answer (score 0):

It is checking if `$id` is not null or not than assigning the result in `$isCopy` variable which is either true or false

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
if ($isCopy = null !== $id) {
```

PHP will evaluated operators according to it's evalutation rules. Comparision operators (such as `!==`) are evaluated before `=`.

So `null !== $id` is evaluated first. null is compared with `id`. Note this is not-identical comparision operator `!==` so it will evaluate true (if `id` is not null in value and type) or false (`id` is not null in value and type).

Finally the assignment operation `$isCopy` is assigned to the comparision result. It will either be true or false.

`$isCopy` will be true if `$id` is not null type, and so the if statement will only be processed if `id` is not null type.

Note that `$id` could have a false value here but not be null type.

Although not logically required by PHP, it is preferred to enforce precedence with parentheses. Parentheses have the highest operator precedence. This makes the code clearer, and can help eliminate errors when a programmer is not sure of the order of operator evaluation.

```
if ($isCopy = (null !== $id)) {
```